# IntelliJ IDEA: stop formating copyright header

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Is there any way I can stop IntelliJ IDEA from formatting the copyright header of Java files?

We have set up a copyright profile for our Java files, which works fine. But formatting the code (via Code > Reformat Code or pre commit option) applies the JavaDoc format for the copyright header. While the format is correct for all JavaDoc comments the copyright header should be ignored.

Comment: Does your copyright header start with /** ? Generally speaking, it shouldn't, as it's not a JavaDoc comment. It should start with /*

Comment: Yes it does, as the we have Borders > Separator before and Separator after enabled, which adds a line with /***... at the beginning.

Comment: The obvious fix is to remove those borders.

Comment: Sure, but unfortunately these are given and can not be removed. And IntelliJ supports those border in the copyright template.

Comment: @yole we have the same issue and don't use these Borders

Answer (score 0):

You could try enabling `Formatter Control`

```
/**
 * @formatter:off
 * <copyright header>
 * @formatter:on
 */
```

It's located in the settings/preferences under `Editor > Code Style > Formatter Control`

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude some part of the source file from being reformatted in intelliJ Idea.

Got to `File -> Settings -> Code Style`, select the `Formatter`tab, and you'll have 3 options (tldr, 3rd is the best for you and me I guess, but I develop the 2 others anyway):

For the sake of the example I'll use my current client's copyright, whose 1st line starts with a `/` folowed by at least 5 `*` (actually a bigger fixed number) and whose last line is at least 5 `*` (actually a bigger fixed number), folowed by a `/`, like this (and we don't want to add a space character on the line with the text)
[image]

**1st option:**
Change the `@formatter:off` and `@formatter:on` if you don't plan to use them. Use regular expression instead, matching the beginning line and the end line of your copyright header.

[image]

**2nd option:**
use the `Do not format` parameter which will recognize the whole block of thing not to format (Maybe this option will only work on 1 line, I don't know how intelliJ resolves the glob patterns so sorry, I can't provide an example, but it may help)

**3rd option (the best):**
a fix to 1st proposal to keep both `@formatter:off` and your regexp may be to use a regexp that would recognize both patterns, like this:
[image]

here are copy-pastable entries `@formatter:off|/\*{5}` `@formatter:on|\*{5}/`